# Laravel export csv file with 'use_bom'=>true can't render text with correct encode

Tags: laravel, utf-8, character-encoding, export-to-csv, shift-jis

I use `'use_bom' => true` to read Japanese in CSV files when opening with Excel. I call through postman everything is fine, but when I call the API via FE, I get a Japanese font error.

I tried changing the content-type content-encode in the header, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried searching with the keyword "bomb csv" and I did the following

- before

  `href={data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(dataCSV,)}}`
- after

  `href={data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent('\uFEFF' + dataCSV,)}}`

so the returned csv file does not have font errors anymore. I don't understand why but glad I fixed it anyway